# How can I use a URL server to show an off-line map?

Tags: html, server, openlayers, openstreetmap

1. I have a web server with URL: https://docker......./overpass/api/
2. How can I use this to get a OSM source in my html file?
   Like change this part:
   new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()})
   Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `var map = new ol.Map({target: 'map',layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()}),],view: [new ol.View({center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([8.788422, 48.87777]),          zoom: 16,}),], });`

How to use URL server as source part?